# Pandas calculate difference on two DataFrames with column and multi-indices

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, diff, pandas-groupby

I have 2 DataFrames, `df1` is:

```
         Jan17  Jun18  Dec18  Apr19
ID Name                            
0  Nick   10.0    1.7    3.7    0.0
1  Jack   10.0    0.0    2.8    3.5
2  Fox    10.0    1.7    0.0    0.0
3  Rex     1.0    0.0    3.0    4.2
```

the second DataFrame - `df2` is:

```
          Jan17  Jun18  Dec18  Apr19
ID Name                             
0  Nick     5.0    1.7    2.0    0.0
1  Jack     6.0    0.0    0.8    3.5
2  Fox      8.0    5.0    0.0    0.0
3  Rex      1.0    0.0    1.0    4.2
4  Snack    3.1    9.0    2.8    4.4
5  Yosee    4.3    0.0    0.0    4.3
6  Petty    0.5    1.3    2.8    3.5
7  Lind     3.6    7.5    2.8    4.3
8  Korr     0.6    1.5    1.8    2.3
```

Result is `df3`:

```
ID   Name        Jan17  Jun18    Dec18    Apr19  
 0   Nick         5.0      0      1.7      0    
 1   Jack         4.0      0      2.0      0              
 2   Fox          2.0      -3.3   0        0    
 3   Rex          0        0      2.0      0
```

How to calculate differences between columns in `df1` and `df2` based on multi-indices: `[ID, Name]` of `df1` and save result to the `df3`?

I'd appreciate for any idea. Thanks!

Comment: Are ID and Name already set as the index of their respective dataframes?

Comment: @cs95, yes, I set it by ```df1.set_index(['ID','Name'], inplace=True)```, ```df2.set_index(['ID','Name'], inplace=True)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just subtract, subtraction is aligned on the index. You can reindex `df2` before subtracting to avoid NaNs:

```
# df1 - df2.reindex(df1.index)
df1.sub(df2.reindex(df1.index))

         Jan17  Jun18  Dec18  Apr19
ID Name                            
0  Nick    5.0    0.0    1.7    0.0
1  Jack    4.0    0.0    2.0    0.0
2  Fox     2.0   -3.3    0.0    0.0
3  Rex     0.0    0.0    2.0    0.0
```

Note that the reason I went for `reindex` over `loc` was to avoid `KeyError`s if there are missing index values.

In the above instance, the first solution will produce NaNs, so you can specify `fill_values` to `reindex` to ensure `df1`'s value is returned (rather than NaN):

```
df2.reindex(df1.index, fill_value=0)

         Jan17  Jun18  Dec18  Apr19
ID Name                            
0  Nick    5.0    1.7    2.0    0.0
1  Jack    6.0    0.0    0.8    3.5
2  Fox     8.0    5.0    0.0    0.0
3  Rex     1.0    0.0    1.0    4.2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do

```
df1-df2.loc[df1.index]
```

Output:

```
         Jan17  Jun18  Dec18  Apr19
ID Name                            
0  Nick    5.0    0.0    1.7    0.0
1  Jack    4.0    0.0    2.0    0.0
2  Fox     2.0   -3.3    0.0    0.0
3  Rex     0.0    0.0    2.0    0.0
```

Comment: loc will raise a KeyError if some index is missing. reindex is safer

Answer (score 1):

Try something new

```
sum(df1.align(0-df2,join='left'))
Out[282]: 
         Jan17  Jun18  Dec18  Apr19
ID Name                            
0  Nick    5.0    0.0    1.7    0.0
1  Jack    4.0    0.0    2.0    0.0
2  Fox     2.0   -3.3    0.0    0.0
3  Rex     0.0    0.0    2.0    0.0
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.sub(*df1.align(df2, join='left'))`

Comment: @WeNYoBen, Can I ask you, why there is ```0 - df2```? Thanks